# geom_desnity Error in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I'm working on creating a `ggplot_density` graph in R but keep receiving the below error:-

My data is as follows:-

```
head(price)

 > head(trades2017)
       MONTH TOTAL
  1    APRIL 69741
  2   AUGUST 61162
  3 DECEMBER 96429
  4 FEBRUARY 81338
  5  JANUARY 80384
  6     JULY 49167
```

I run the below and it returns an error:-

```
  ggplot(data=trades2017, aes(TOTAL,color=MONTH)) +
  geom_density(position="identity", alpha = 0.3)
```

> Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing

I tried creating a layer as well but received the same error:-

```
  ggplot(data=trades2017, aes(TOTAL,color=MONTH)) +
  layer(geom="density", stat="identity")
```

> Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing

What I'm trying to do is create a plot with density to show trade volume over the course of the year.

However, I keep receiving the same error upon multiple revisions of the `ggplot_density`.

Is it possible to create a density plot with both y and x values or only x values?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how `color=MONTH` can possibly make sense since color there is supposed to identify subsets and month identifies rows.  Try dropping that.

Comment: Unless you don't have many years, you might want to try something like `ggplot(trades2017, aes(y = TOTAL, x = factor(MONTH, levels = toupper(month.name)))) + geom_col() + xlab("Month")`, which makes more sense to me.

Comment: I'm really confused by what your goal is. You ask about creating `density` with `x` and `y` values, but you only have one numeric column and you map it to `x`. You don't map anything to `y`. And how do you want the color to go? Based on your data frame name I assume you have one row for each month - and you want each row to be a different color? Do you know what densities are? My best guess is you want a bar plot with MONTH on the x axis and TOTAL on the y axis. Or maybe a line plot.

Comment: Thank you. My preference would have a color for each month which is based off of the total volume (density). I will try some of these variations as I currently have a plot with a line but was trying to create a graph with a bit more visibility for each month.

Comment: Would you agree that [a density plot see link for example](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/density_plot.html) seems like a bad fit?